# How to make segue pass string works?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am trying a segue to pass a string from a view controller to another view controller but it's not working.

Xcode 10, Swift 4, iOS 10.

viewcontroller.swift code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segue_vc_to_myvc" {
            let vc = segue.destination as! MyViewController
            vc.str = "hello"
        }
    }
}
```

Myviewcontroller.swift:

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label:UILabel!

    var str: String? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //label.text = str
        if let str = str {
            print(str)
        }
    }
```

I want to show the string on screen, but it's nothing. I tried to use a label and it still has nothing.

If I use `label.text = str`,  the error messages is:

```
self    _0190603.MyViewController   0x000000010130a490
UIKit.UIViewController  UIViewController    
label   UILabel?    nil none
str String? nil none
```

[set the break point and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ly1p.jpg)

[segue.identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qgdb6.jpg)

[the label have nothing...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9hJn.jpg)

Comment: are you sur you go through `if segue.identifier == "segue_vc_to_myvc" { }`statement ? double check your segue identifier

Comment: It looks as if your UILabel outlet is not connected in the Storyboard (and the problems is unrelated to passing data between view controllers).

Comment: set a breakpoint at `vc.str = "hello"`

Comment: identifier is "segue_vc_to_myvc".

Comment: set a breakpoint at vc.str=....
get the error message is : Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: i update 3 pics in my post, you can help me to check it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard check the Segue's identifier between the two page.
[image]

then make sure you trigger the right way to preform the segue.

something like this

```
@IBAction func NextPageAction(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "second_page", sender: nil)
}
```

add a break point at 'if segue.identifier == blablabla' and see what happening here

```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "second_page" {
            let page = segue.destination as! SecondeViewController
            page.txt = "hello world"
        }
    }
```

Comment: the identifier is "segue_vc_to_myvc".

Answer (score 0):

check whether you have set the identifier correctly. It should work as it is!

Comment: i can't add comment with photo.
and my identifier is "segue_vc_to_myvc".

Comment: Try deleting the segue and adding a fresh one. Sometimes it helps!

Comment: Also check whether you have used the same segue identifier for some other segue perhaps?

Comment: I have try it and still the same.